# Generate all combinations of characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to output all the possible combinations of 4 character strings using uppercase letters.

```
function makeid(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

function getcodes(){
 var newcode =makeid(4);
 if (codes.includes(newcode)){
    getcodes();   
 }
 else 
 {
    codes.push(newcode) 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += newcode + "<br>";
    getcodes();   
  }
} 
getcodes() 
console.log(codes.length)
```

The problem, of course, is that this loops forever. I'm not sure how to stop the loop when all the codes have been generated. How can I stop this after all combinations have been created?

The use case is that we're trying to generate unique URLs that will be something like example.com/CODES-HERE The codes generated with this script will be used for the CODES-HERE part.

Comment: Can you at least leave a small note, as to why you intend to solve a combinatorical problem with random?

Comment: @ASDFGerte Just added. The use case is that we're trying to generate unique URLs that will be something like example.com/CODES-HERE The codes generated with this script will be used for the CODES-HERE part.

Comment: If your intentions are simply to generate the combinations, then don't use random, search on SO (or other sites) for one of the 832475342 solutions for "generate all combinations", and use that?

Comment: Why would you use random numbers? It literally is nested loops.

Comment: @epascarello what random numbers?

Comment: um Math.random()

Comment: Can you give me some direction on the nested loops then?

Comment: Do you just want to generate one random combination and insure it's unique right, or generate all 456976 combinations?

Comment: @MarkMeyer All combinations

Answer (score 1):

```js
// there are 26! / (4! * 22!) = 14950 combinations possible. it takes a lot of time to get all those by trying random characters 
const chrs = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
// function that returns the cartesian product of two arrays, excluding combinations with repeating characters or 
// not in alphabetic order (because ACB is the same combination with ABC)
const cartesian = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.flatMap(x => arr2.filter(v => x < v[0]).map(y => x + y));
const combs = (ra, n) => [...Array(n - 2)].reduce(a => cartesian(ra, a), cartesian(ra, ra));
const str = combs([...chrs], 4).reduce((a, v) => a + v + '<br>', '');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
// if you want to allow combinations with repeating characters or not in alphabetic order
// remove the filter from cartesian
// but there are 26 ** 4 = 456976 possible outcomes then, so it'll take some time to print them all
```